# How to have nested double pointers without structs in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, void-pointers

Here I have the following code:

```
void **x;

void
push(void * value) {
  void *a = x[1];
  int *b = (int*)(&a[0]);
  printf("%d\n", *b);
  (((void*)&a))[*b + 1] = *value;
}

void
init() {
  void **a;
  void **b;

  a = malloc(sizeof(void*) * 100);
  b = malloc(sizeof(void*) * 100);
  x = malloc(sizeof(void*) * 10000);

  a[0] = (0);
  b[0] = (0);

  x[0] = a;
  x[1] = b;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
  init();
  push(argv);
  x[3] = "e";
  x[4] = "e";
  puts(x[4]);
}
```

Essentially, my goal is to have an arbitrarily-sized array `x` which *can contain arbitrary nested elements*. Then I want to treat `a` in `init` as also a double void pointer so it too can have anything. I plan on simply making it a dynamically sized array of integers. Then `b` I want to contain a fixed number of arbitrary elements.

However, I have tried dozens of combinations of pointers and references and am at this point simply going by trial and error. Getting this on one of the latest configurations.

```
$ make test
test/test.c:19:25: error: incomplete type 'void' is not assignable
  (((void*)&a))[*b + 1] = *value;
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

I don't really have a super solid grasp of the pointers to accomplish this and wondering if one could point me in the right direction.

Comment: As a clarification, in line `a[0] = (0);` are you trying to assign the value zero to a[0] or trying to set a[0] to `NULL`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this without structs? If your arrays can be arbitrarily nested you must be able to tell whether an entry is an integer or another array, no? The canonical way to do that in C is to use a tagged union. (You could do some bit-fiddling on the raw pointer values, but ...)

Comment: `void` pointers can't be dereferenced, because the `void` type is essentially a way of saying "nothing".
IIUC, what you want is `(((void**)&a))[*b+1] = value`. That would say "`a` is a pointer to `void*`, that I'll be treating as an array of `void*`, and I will store the in the position pointed by `*b+1` the `void*` value of `value`". Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to reference to a: `&a`, you have to cast `void **` instead of `void *` because `a` is a pointer at first.

So, it will work (i'm not sure it's thing you want):

```
 (((void**)&a))[*b + 1] = value;
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Now is there any way to clean that line up by dividing it into a few lines with some temp variables or something? It's kind of complex.